# MySQL results by date

Tags: mysql

Maybe there is a simple fix but I can't seam to figure it out. I'll try my best to explain my situation.

I'm working on a MySQL query that will return results within date range (in column A), and for date range - 1 year (in column B). I need to group results by month day and not by year. So I would like to have something like this:

```
        2014       2013
        ----------------
01-01      6          8
01-03      7          0
01-04      4          1
01-08      0         13
01-21     11          7
```

In my current query (below) I get results like this (because of ELSE in CASE):

```
        2014       2013
        ----------------
01-01      0          8
01-03      7          0
01-04      0          1
01-08      0         13
01-21      0          7
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(table.date, '%e.%c.') AS date,
(CASE WHEN DATE(table.date) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-01' THEN ROUND(SUM(table.field), 2) ELSE 0 END) AS field_2014,
(CASE WHEN DATE(table.date) BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-01' THEN ROUND(SUM(table.field), 2) ELSE 0 END) AS field_2013

FROM table

WHERE 
(DATE(table.date) BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-06-01' OR DATE(table.date) BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-06-01')

GROUP BY 
DATE_FORMAT(table.date, '%c.%e.')
```

What should I put in ELSE and how can I achieve this functionality?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Try using sum outer, that is case within 'sum( case(..) ) '

Comment: thnx for your help senk! It did lead me on the right path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need aggregation functions.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.date, '%e.%c.') AS date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN year(t.date) = 2014 THEN ROUND(SUM(t.field), 2) ELSE 0 END) AS field_2014,
       SUM(CASE WHEN year(t.date) = 2013 THEN ROUND(SUM(t.field), 2) ELSE 0 END) AS field_2013
FROM table t
WHERE year(t.date) in (2013, 2014) and month(t.date) = 5
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t.date, '%c.%e.');
```

I would also recommend using the format `'%m-%d'`.  Having the month then the year means that `order by` will work on the column.  Having all the dates be the same width ("05/01" rather than "5/1") better corresponds to your desired output.

Comment: thank you Gordon, your example helped me a lot. I did manage to achieve desired functionality with both your and senk's help. TY